# I cant get the min or the max of a tuple

Tags: python

```
total_price = []

for i in range (5):
try:
     price = list (input ("Enter the price of the sweet: "))
except ValueError:
    print("Enter an integer")
total_price.append(price)
print (total_price)

print ("The most expensive sweet is " + str (max(total_price)))
print ("The least expensive sweet is" + str (min(total_price)))
```

This is what it outputs

```
Enter the price of the sweet: 10
Enter the price of the sweet: 20
Enter the price of the sweet: 30
Enter the price of the sweet: 40
Enter the price of the sweet: 50
[['1', '0'], ['2', '0'], ['3', '0'], ['4', '0'], ['5', '0']]
The most expensive sweet is ['5', '0']
The least expensive sweet is['1', '0']
>>>
```

I have managed to get to that stage but i'm still having issues as for some reason it is separating the values in the array.

Comment: which code you are using?

Comment: Please always include the relevant code and complete error traceback as **text**, not images.

Comment: im developing in python

Comment: You should post your code as text, not in images.

Comment: If you found a solution, please post it as an answer, not inside your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# omitted part
try:
    price = list(input("Enter the price of the sweet: "))
except ValueError:
    print("Enter an integer")
```

Here you change `str` applying `list` to it. For example,

```
read_value = '1234'
list(read_value)
Out:
['1', '2', '3', '4']  # type: list of str
```

To fix this issue, use `int`:

```
# omitted part
try:
    price = int(input("Enter the price of the sweet: "))
except ValueError:
    print("Enter an integer")
```

For single input,

```
read_value = '1234'
int(read_value)
Out:
1234  # type: int
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is telling you the problem, total_price is not iterable because it's an int, it's like asking what max(7) is. You probably want to do something like store all 5 inputs in some array and then call sum, max, min on that array.

Example --

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(max(A)) # 5
print(min(A)) # 1
print(sum(A)) # 15
```

Comment: Could you please add some examples to improve your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `max` function, which expects an iterable or more than two arguments to select the higher value as its definition says:

> Return the largest item in an iterable or the largest of two or more arguments",

But you are passing an integer

Comment: if i were to store it in an array how would i go about doing that?

Comment: `prices = [] prices.append(some_value)`

Comment: i have tried this but for some reason it is separating the values in the array. I've updated my original post with what i've got currently.

Answer (score 0):

If you store the prices in a list, which is iterable, you can then find the price of the most expensive sweet. Such as:

```
prices = []
for i in range(5):
   try:
      sweet_price = int(input("Enter price: "))
   except ValueError:
      print("ErrorMessage")
   prices.append(sweet_price)

highest_price = max(prices)
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max

> For finding max in tuple, such as the title suggests, try `max(list(prices))`